# Is there some kind of IsChanged event of Kendo Grid editable popup?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Apologies in advance, I almost never write javascript so this is all very unfamiliar to me. I have a kendo grid with an editable popup for editing records. That popup contains a multiselect where the user can choose multiple cities. If I want to detect if that field has been changed, and set a property on my model for it how do I go about that? Here is the relevant section in my popup edit function, the multiselect is just bound to a standard datasource

```
editable: "popup",
    edit(evt){

        var msCities = container.find("#Cities");
            msCities.kendoMultiSelect({
               dataSource: dsCities
               , dataTextField: "City"
               , dataValueField: "ID"
           });  

         //msCities.changed? 

     });
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger a function adding change: onChangeFunctionName to your multiselect

```
editable: "popup",
edit(evt){

    var msCities = container.find("#Cities");
        msCities.kendoMultiSelect({
           dataSource: dsCities
           , dataTextField: "City"
           , dataValueField: "ID",
             change: onChangeFunctionName
       });  

     //msCities.changed? 

 });


onChangeFunctionName function() {
// your function 
    }
```

Comment: Oh of course! I was over-complicating it in my head thinking it had to be some unique property on the grid or something, thanks for the help